# How can i do this by Function correct me

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tabels `mangers` (don't have names), and `Employees` (has all names).
I want to get the function the employee name and returns his manager name

```
create or alter function funTest (@employee varchar(max))
                returns varchar(max)
as
begin
declare @manager varchar(max)

select @manager = (select @manager = m.empname from employees e,employees m , departments d
                    where e.empid=d.managerid and .deptid=d.deptid
                    and @employees =e.empname)
return @manager
end
```

Not: I did it by `procedure`

Comment: Sample data and desired outputs will be a great explanation.

Comment: `.deptid=d.deptid` ? and better to use modern `JOINS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, This is possible, But you might need some small changes, try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION funTest 
(
   @employee varchar(max)
)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin

   declare @manager varchar(max)

   select 
     @manager = m.empname from employees e,employees m , departments d
                where e.deptid = d.deptid and d.managerid=m.empid
                and e.empname=@employee

   return @manager

end
```

Comment: `.deptid=d.deptid`? don't copy/paste the same typo.

Comment: Also `create or alter function` isn't valid in sql server

Comment: I have Updated the query

Comment: As per his current Query, I feel like It's e.deptid because he wants to get the employee department. But If he misses any other columns, then he might provide us with the table structure. But It doesn't feel like that Join is needed there. So Mya be he is missing some columns or the join to department is not needed.

Comment: So close @JayasuryaSatheesh
thanks
,,, and i edit it to return the true value